# How to: Insert a specific string in a two Dimensional string array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

How can i for example start the grid array already with the letter "S" at the coordenate (1,1)?

```
public class Generator {
private static int row = 5;
private static int col = 5;
private static String[][] grid = new String[row][col];



public static void Grid_Generator() {


    String AB = "_W";

    SecureRandom rnd = new SecureRandom();
    for (int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(row);
        for (int j = 0; j < grid[i].length; j++) {
            sb.append(AB.charAt(rnd.nextInt(AB.length())));
            sb.toString();
            grid[i][j] = sb.toString();





        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be apreciated.

Comment: `grid[1][1] = "S"` ? What are you actually asking?

Comment: yeah you are right, i dont know why but i convinced myself that i already had tryied that and it didnt work. Thanks anyway.

Comment: What is the purpose of statement `sb.toString();`? What do you believe that statement does?

Comment: hmm that line isn´t doing anything since i already do that in grid[i][j] = sb.toString(); i only putted like that because someone suggested it to me. i guess i will remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this code immediately following your `grid` declaration:

```
static {
   grid[1][1] = "S";
}
```

The thing above is called a **`static initialization block`** and it is run when the class is loaded, right after `grid` is created (since `grid` is also static, it gets set when the class is loaded as well).

Anyways, you should note that **all** arrays in Java start with the index `0`, not `1`, so setting `grid[1][1]` equal to `"S"` would give you a matrix like this (`grid[1][1] = "S";`):

```
[ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ]
[ ] [S] [ ] [ ] [ ]
[ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ]
...
```

Not a matrix like this (`grid[0][0] = "S";`):

```
[S] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ]
[ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ]
[ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ]
...
```

On a side note, you are calling `sb.toString();` in your `GridGenerator()` method. This does nothing, so I removed it from below. :/

Anyways, after modifying your code with the changes I've suggested, you should get this:

```
public class Generator {
private static int row = 5;
private static int col = 5;
private static String[][] grid = new String[row][col];

static {
   grid[1][1] = "S";
}

public static void Grid_Generator() {

   String AB = "_W";

   SecureRandom rnd = new SecureRandom();
   for (int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(row);
       for (int j = 0; j < grid[i].length; j++) {
           sb.append(AB.charAt(rnd.nextInt(AB.length())));
           grid[i][j] = sb.toString();
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help.